# How to remove a specific string from a character on multiple rows of data?

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with a column for ID, it is a varchar, this column however has to be 14 characters long. The vendor that supplies this table left some with 15 characters. The format of the number is 'FL000000123456.' So, we asked them and they told us to just remove off the leading zero. I need to run an update on this table to remove that first zero, but I do not how to do that. I ran the LEN function to bring me back the ones that have a LEN of > 14. I can replace or run an update on the individual basis, but the table has over 1 million records and about 45,000 of them have the > 14 error. I do not work on SQL most of my time, so I am not as adept as some of you will be, but any help I can get would be greatly appreciated.

output: FL0000000123456 -- 15 chars

desired output: FL000000123456 -- 14 chars

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Assuming* that therefore you want to remove the `3rd` character, you could use `STUFF`:

```sql
SELECT STUFF(YourColumn,3,1,'') AS NewColumn
FROM dbo.YourTable
WHERE LEN(YourColumn) = 15;
```

Of course, this does mean if you have a value like `'FL1234567891234'` you would end up with `'FL234567891234'`, but I am *assuming* that won't happen.

Comment: Thank you for teaching me about the STUFF function, I didn't know it existed, this worked perfectly, I appreciate you taking the time to help me with this matter.

Comment: @Larnu Can we use Replace as well?
SELECT Replace(YourColumn,'FL0','FL') AS NewColumn
FROM dbo.YourTable
WHERE LEN(YourColumn) = 15;

Comment: That would work too, provided `'FL'` can't appear anywhere other than as a prefix, @RajanPatekar .